# when i am going to take build appbundle I have an error

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to make an app bundle I get the following error:

```
    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    Note: `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_messaging-14.7.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.`

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
   > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 21s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             82.3s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I updated the packages but this was not solved

Answer (score 1):

Usually `signReleaseBundle` issue indicates that you have not added the keys that are necessary to create the bundle.

You need to upload your key file. If you are using Windows, it should be like this:

```
"C:/key/myapp/upload-keystore.jks"
```